# How to run TestNG failed test cases in Jenkins for Maven project?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and I have configured it on my Windows PC. I have to run failed test cases twice before considering that they are failing. I am using TestNG and Selenium Webdriver for writing test cases.

I have created a job in Jenkins which maps to my workspace and runs the `testng.xml`. I have specified the path of `testng.xml` in `pom.xml`. I have created a maven project and I run the `pom.xml` for running my test cases.

Now after a successful run of all test cases, I get surefire reports of the tests. I want to run the failed test cases i.e `testng-failed.xml` twice. I have tried running it using the following command in the post build section:

```
cd path to workspace
mvn test -DtestNG.file=/target/surefire-reports/testng-failed.xml
```

But when I run the above command it runs `testng.xml` instead of running `testng-failed.xml`. I am not sure if I am on the correct path for running failed test cases.

I need help guys. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Someone on stackoverflow answered this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713564/restart-failed-test-case-automatically-in-testng-selenium

Comment: I want to execute failed test cases after complete execution of test suite. Suppose there were 1000 test cases and 200 failed then I want to run that 200 again and suppose if 150 failed again I want to run this 150 again and the final test report would generate. Also I want to achieve this with jenkins.

Comment: I think if your test case is failed then no need to re-run again and again.Reason for that you have to check that test case manually , may be there is bug in system. Automation is not for prove that test case is always get pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like this

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the VM argument line used for unit tests are run. -->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <suiteXmlFile>target/surefire-reports/testngfailed.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, failed xml file is not present, so we get below error `org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process`

Answer (score 1):

Form above explanation it seems that failed-testng.xml gets deleted when you re-run your tests in Post task under Jenkins, because when you run "mvn clean" it will delete the target folder where failed-testng.xml was present.
To verify this you need to access the Jenkins workspace, but your software testing company might not have the access to it.

Further follow these steps they will solve the issue:

First your pom should be configurable to run the tests from command line:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <forkCount>0</forkCount>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Then configure jenkins for the Post build(which is you already doing) to run the failed-testng.xml.

But first you have to copy/move the failed-testng.xml to from target folder to any other folder within framework(except target and test-output folder, because these folders gets deleted when you run the command "mvn clean").

Below is the Maven plugin to copy/move file from one location to another location:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <!-- here the phase you need -->
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/failed-testng.xml</outputDirectory>
          <resources>          
            <resource>
              <directory>src/</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>              
        </configuration>            
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Note: This plugin must be executed after the tests execution.

Answer (score 0):

Is switching to jUnit an option?

With jUnit and the surefire plugin for maven, you can can start your tests with a parameter that will restart your testcase in case it failed.

mvn -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=5 test
where 5 is the maximum number of restart on fail accepted until it will generate an error.

more info can be found here: https://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html

Answer (score 0):

See there is another way to check your failed testcase is really failed due to your mistake or any other things(e.g. if element is not getting due to synchronization ot stale element is seen then those issues  are in your script)
Any way you have to use Analyzer and transformer interfaces of testng to run failed testcase more than one.